# How to define a Constant in XSD

Tags: xsd, constants

Is there a way to define a constant value and use that constant in the preceeding XSD? I have a common value I want to use for various xs:element tag's maxOccurs attributes.  Like constants in other languages, I want to make the change in one place should the value backing MyConst were to ever change.

```
<!-- Can I do this? -->
<ConstantValue id="MyConst" value="10"/>
...
<xs:element name="sandwich_meat" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="MyConst"/>
<xs:element name="sandwich_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="MyConst"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not allowed that way. However you can define your own type with a fixed value in it somewhere on top of your XSD (place dosen matters) and use that type for the elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to define a simpleType with a restriction:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="AConstantHere">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="CONSTANT_VALUE_HERE"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

It allows only one value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with plain schema, but maybe XML [entities](http://www.javacommerce.com/displaypage.jsp?name=entities.sql&id=18238) will do the trick?